# Connection of Perpendicular in right triangle

Tags: triangles, pythagorean-triples

[image]

I am sorry first, my mother language is not English so I have a problem to explain ‘what I want to know’. But I will try my best.

The Pythagorean rule said that “C^2=ab”.  And I understood if a=b, then it become a=b=c.
But if a and b is not the same length, why C^2 still is ab?? I want to understand the prove. Thank you for reading.

Comment: "I figured out that $c^2=ab$." "why $c^2$ is still $ab$?" these statements are contradictory.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I meant if there is other way to prove ‘c^2=ab’.

Comment: Use Pythagorean formula to find the square on the hypotenuse of the triangle with legs $a$ and $c$, do the same for the triangle with legs $b$ and $c$, and then again for the one with hypotenuse $a+b$, but compute this one in two different ways.

Comment: Consider the two small triangles. They are similar, so $a/c = c/b$.

Comment: This is not at all what most people recognize as the Pythagorean Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

All of the triangles are similar so the ratios of their sides are the same. This means we can multiply both sides by the denominator product and get

$$\dfrac{a}{c}=\dfrac{c}{b}\implies
a\cdot b=c\cdot c$$

The smallest Pythgorean triple with an integer for diagonal $\,c\,$ is shown here. Using extended manipulation of the Pythagorean Theorem, we can derive $\quad c=\dfrac{AB}{C}\quad$ which can also be verified by inspection of this example.

[image]